# How do i create following cardview in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, material-ui, android-cardview

[image]

How can i create this type cardview any suggestions for this layout please help me

Comment: You mean the design? It's just a custom background drawable or just background with TextView on top. For the layout you can make it in ConstraintLayout or GridLayout in RecyclerView

Comment: background of cardview how can design like that

Comment: Well, you need some vector drawables for the background and then create a child LinearLayout or RelativeLayout for the CardView and apply that drawable as background of the child.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RecyclerView and set layout manager as Grid Layout manager like below

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
```